# Thread.interrupt() ignored

Tags: java, multithreading, javasound

I am trying to write an algorithm which calculates the volume of a soundcard input. While this is (more or less) not the problem, I run into trouble while multitasking. The interrupts I call from another Thread seem to be ignored.

I developed multithreaded environments before and I think I know the pitfalls of `Thread.isInterrupted()` vs. `Thread.interrupted()` and the `InterruptedException` - that's why I use `Thread.isInterrupted()` exclusively. *Edit*: Also I think nothing I use here throws `InterruptedException`.

So I wrote this class:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundListener extends Thread {

    /**
     * RMS refresh rate in Hz (1000ms / RESPONSE_TIME)
     */
    private static final int REFRESH_RATE = 40;

    private final SoundMeter SOUNDMETER;
    private final AudioFormat AUDIO_FORMAT;
    private final int BUFFER_SIZE;
    private final boolean IS_24_BITS;
    private final TargetDataLine TARGET_DATA_LINE;

    SoundListener(SoundMeter soundMeter, Mixer mixer, AudioFormat audioFormat) throws LineUnavailableException {
        SOUNDMETER = soundMeter;
        AUDIO_FORMAT = audioFormat;
        BUFFER_SIZE = (int) ((AUDIO_FORMAT.getSampleRate() * AUDIO_FORMAT.getSampleSizeInBits()) / REFRESH_RATE);
        IS_24_BITS = AUDIO_FORMAT.getSampleSizeInBits() == 24;
        TARGET_DATA_LINE = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(AUDIO_FORMAT, mixer.getMixerInfo());
        TARGET_DATA_LINE.open(AUDIO_FORMAT);
        TARGET_DATA_LINE.start();

        setName("SoundListener");
        setDaemon(true);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Thread " + getName() + " started!");

        while (!isInterrupted()) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = TARGET_DATA_LINE.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

            if (bytesRead >= 0) {

                int max = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; ) {

                    byte[] subBuffer = new byte[3];
                    subBuffer[0] = buffer[i++];
                    subBuffer[1] = buffer[i++];

                    if (IS_24_BITS) {
                        subBuffer[2] = buffer[i++];
                    }

                    int currentValue = 0;
                    if (AUDIO_FORMAT.isBigEndian()) {
                        if (IS_24_BITS) {
                            currentValue += subBuffer[0] << 16;
                            currentValue += subBuffer[1] << 8;
                            currentValue += subBuffer[2];
                        } else {
                            currentValue += subBuffer[0] << 8;
                            currentValue += subBuffer[1];
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (IS_24_BITS) {
                            currentValue += subBuffer[2] << 16;
                        }
                        currentValue += subBuffer[0];
                        currentValue += subBuffer[1] << 8;
                    }

                    if (currentValue > max) {
                        max = currentValue;
                    }
                }
                SOUNDMETER.setVolume(max);
            }
        }
        TARGET_DATA_LINE.close();

        System.out.println("Thread " + getName() + " stopped!");
    }
}
```

It starts the input interface on initialization and then right away starts itself.

The class `SoundMeter` is the external class which manages the Mixer to use and initializes the Thread as well as invoking the interrupt on the Thread object (*Edit*: This class also receives calculated volume values).

I think the problem is the blocking `TargetDataLine.read()` method but I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Most likely not related, but it is worth pointing out that many unusual problems come from extending Thread class. We should avoid it. Instead always prefer to implement class representing task which in Java is Runnable, and passing that task to Thread instance (which represents worker handling that task).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the interrupt API, I'd just use a `boolean` flag `isRunning` in this case, and set it to `false` when the thread should stop.

The flag set by [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) may not be observable to us, particularly when the thread is blocking:

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the `wait()`, `wait(long)`, or `wait(long, int)` methods of the `Object` class, or of the `join()`, `join(long)`, `join(long, int)`, `sleep(long)`, or `sleep(long, int)`, methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an `InterruptedException`.

Since `TargetDataLine.read` says it may block, there's no reason to expect that `isInterrupted()` will work here.

It would be nice if `TargetDataLine` would interrupt itself again to set the flag for us when it receives an `InterruptedException`, but there's nothing saying it has to.

Comment: While I knew that part of the docs I thought it would not fit my case since I don't invoke any of the mentioned methods. However, the custom boolean flag worked (as I expected) but I thought this is what the interrupt API is there for, that's why I tried that approach first. Seems this is not the case (or not in each use case for that matter) unfortunately.

Comment: When the `TargetDataLine.read` doc says it blocks, it's implying that it calls one of those methods which means that it will catch the `InterruptedException` sometimes. For example, on Mac OS, the `TargetDataLine` implementation is a `com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL`, and, well, [you can see it call wait right here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/media/sound/DirectAudioDevice.java#1031) and it just eats the exception.

Comment: So it does what we all were told not to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Thread.interrupt() in common way just set the flag and that's all

> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.

So you thread will be ended during the first check while (!isInterrupted()) after your call Thread.interrupt()